# Uncountable followed by countable nouns - "is" or "are"?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, modifiers

I have a question about the following sentence:

> The only artwork in evidence is/are some Greek vases and terracotta objects.

Is it "artwork" that selects the verb-form (therefore "is"), or "Greek vases and terracotta objects" ("are")?

I know the problem could be solved by saying "artworks", but in the context it's talking about a lack of artwork in the surroundings in general, i.e. wall frescoes, mosaics, carvings etc, so the uncountable "artwork" is more appropriate.

Comment: `The only artworks/works of art in evidence are some Greek vases and terracotta objects.`

Comment: Singular "is" is fine, despite the number mismatch between the singular subject and the plural predicative.

Comment: 'The only artwork is evidenced by some Greek vases and terracotta objects.'

Answer (score -1):

The verb should agree with the number and person of the subject, not of the object. 
In the sentence in question,the subject *The artwork* is uncountable ( singular).  So, the verb should agree with it, that is *is*.

As a collective noun *[artwork](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/artwork)* means:

> the pieces of art, such as drawings and photographs, that are used in
>   books, newspapers, and magazines:

*All the artwork in the book has been done by the author.*